# How to get netezza query output in the following fomrm?

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm a beginner in netezza, I have a table called employee with three columns, first_name, last_name and dept. I need the output of select query in the following form. Each row of the query should be a new line in the output.

Table:- Employee
Columns: first_name, last_name, dept

Note:- I was able to do this in oracle database using xml_forest function but i couldn't find equivalent xml function in netezza.

```
<First_name>Adam</First_name><Last_name>Santner</Last_name></dept>hr</dept>
<First_name>John</First_name><Last_name>Milne</Last_name><dept>hr</dept>
<First_name>Mike</First_name><Last_name>Tyson</Last_name><dept>hr</dept>
```

Answer (score 0):

Netezza XML processing is included in a add-on bundle called SQL Extension Toolkit.  You can download it IBM Fix central.  Here is the documentation link that describes how to utilize the functionality

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=functions-publishing-sql-data-as-xml